# How can I take a mixed tuple containing a list and change it to a flat tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following tuple:

```
tuple = ('string1', ['string2', [1,2,3,4]])
```

I want it to be flattened so:

```
tuple = ('string1', 'string2', [1,2,3,4])
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `(t[0], *t[1])`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the existing instance so you need to create a new one.

```py
array = ('string1', ['string2', [1,2,3,4]])
result = []
for element in array:
    if isinstance(element, list):
        result.extend(element)
    else:
        result.append(element)

print(result)
# ['string1', 'string2', [1, 2, 3, 4]]

final_tuple = tuple(result)

print(final_tuple)
 # ('string1', 'string2', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never choose the word tuple as a variable because it is a keyword in Python and it will cause problems for your program.

I don't know if there is a special function for this or not?
But to flatten the desired tuple, I wrote this piece of code:

```
my_tuple = ('string1', ['string2', [1,2,3,4]])

temp_list = []
for item in my_tuple:
    if isinstance(item , list) or isinstance(item , tuple):
        for component in item:
            temp_list.append(component)
    else:
        temp_list.append(item)

my_tuple = tuple(temp_list)
print(my_tuple)
```

Note: This code works for all situations where a list or tuple is inside another list or tuple, for example:

a = ('string1', ['string2', [1,2,3,4]], 34, ({"a": 12, "b": 16}, "string3"))

*result --> ('string1', 'string2', [1, 2, 3, 4], 34, {'a': 12, 'b': 16}, 'string3')*

b = [1, 2, 3, ["Sara", "Alex"] , [23.56, 100.89, 13.82]]

*result --> (1, 2, 3, 'Sara', 'Alex', 23.56, 100.89, 13.82)*

Comment: Instead of `for component in item: temp_list.append(component)`, you could use `.extend(item)`